# Community Email Notification

Tags: community

In Salesforce community, Setting and Preferences are available in User profile menu. In that Email notification is available with checkbox. In which object is the field value stored?

Answer (score 2):

There are several fields on the [`User` object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_user.htm) that control different facets of email notification:

- `DefaultGroupNotificationFrequency` is the default value for Chatter group email notifications.
- There are a number of preferences with API names like `UserPreferencesDisableXXXXXEmail`, which, when set, inhibit emails for Chatter feature XXXXX. Examples include `UserPreferencesDisableBookmarkEmail`, `UserPreferencesDisableChangeCommentEmail`, and so on. I suspect these are what you're thinking of in representing different email-related checkboxes on the user profile.